# Unable to fetch Current User IP in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get visitor IP address on My AP.Net website.

```
 string sd = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

it is supposed to return a valid IP. But returns only

```
::1
```

I can't understand What kind of result is this. Can any one help me on this?

Comment: It's your localhost ip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`::1` **is** a valid IP address. It's the [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) loopback address. The (more familiar) IPv4 equivalent would be `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: What would be the correct way to get complete IP address?

Comment: @Athul: `::1` is the complete IP address. It's the short form for `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001`.

Comment: @Athul it is the complete address, in that if you are running your site in debug mode on your local machine, and are also accessing the site from the same machine, you'll get the loopback address.  If you access the site from a different machine, you'll get a "proper" IP address.

Comment: Thanks  @BrendanGreen . Now I know What is the Issue